# Using nth-child to style mulitiple items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can you use nth-child to style , not for odd, even but for various out of order items ?

I want to style 1,3,7,8 , so how would i do that ?

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/nTZrg/50/

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If it's 'out of order' what defines the 'nth' term?

Comment: You can test using :nth Tester http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Two or more people took time to help you.  Please accept one the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that 1,3,7,8 are random and not some sort of pattern it's fairly simple:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ79y/)

```
ul li:nth-child(1),
ul li:nth-child(3),
ul li:nth-child(7),
ul li:nth-child(8){
    background-color:blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's random numbers I think you need javascript here's a jquery implementation
http://jsfiddle.net/nTZrg/52/

```
 <ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
 <li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
</ul>


var array = [1, 3, 7, 8]

for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
$('ul li').eq(array[i]).prev().addClass('blue')
}



 .blue {
     background-color:blue;
     color: white;
 }
```

Comment: you could hard code with css like below but if you data is dynamic this would be more appropriate